# Setting homegroup in Windows 7 for sharing files on a Network

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, homegroup

I'm running a windows seven system which is connected to the hostel network.There are dozens of connected PC's that are using windows seven.My friends and I wanted to share files with each other on the same network so we tried to create a homegroup. But that doesn't work. Windows seven prompts to join an existing homegroup created by some unknown person rather than giving an option to create one. Is there anyway we can setup our own homegroup?
Or if there is any other good way to share the files with each other without using homegroup.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to consider;

1. In Windows 7 Starter and Windows 7 Home Basic, you can join a HomeGroup, but you can’t create one.
2. Your network location might not be set to Home. HomeGroup only works on home networks.
3. If you are on a domain network, your system administrator might have turned off HomeGroup completely

Also, if you are still having problems setting up a homegroup, here is a link to a Microsoft article - [Why can't I create a homegroup?](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Why-cant-I-create-a-homegroup) This article states:

> Typically, a homegroup is created automatically when you set up a
>   computer with this version of Windows, but there are several things
>   that could prevent you from creating one. To diagnose and fix common
>   problems with creating a homegroup, first try running a Fix It wizard.

Comment: There is an existing homegroup which means that network administrators haven't blocked the creation of a homegroup.At one moment I figured out the person whose homegroup was windows prompting me to join.I asked him to tell me the password of his homegroup which he didn't remember so he simply closed his homegroup.I thought that it would make me able to create my own homegroup but than again I was being prompted to join the homegroup created by some other person.
If I ask network administrators to resolve the situation will that work?
Or if there is any otherway we can share our files mutually?

Comment: If you aren't able to resolve the use of homegourps, you can ask the administrator to setup a shared folder on the network for you to place files to be shared with others.